# Hibernate @Filter does not work with Spring JpaRepository.findById method

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

In order to create row-level authorization, I want to use `@Filter` and `@FilterDef` hibernate annotations in combination with `JpaRepository<T, ID>` interface of [spring-data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html). Suppose that, we have a following entities:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String name;
    
   @ManyToOne
   private Pharmacy pharmacy;
}
    
@Entity
public class Pharmacy {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String name;
}
```

I want to create authorization based on whom send requests to server. For this purpose, I've added `@Filter` and `@FilterDef` annotations top of the `Pharmacy` entity. So, the pharmacy should be like below:

```java
@Entity
@FilterDef(name = "pharmacyFilter", parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "userId", type = "long")})
@Filters({
   @Filter(name = "pharmacyFilter", condition = "id in (select user.pharmacy_id from user where user.id = :userId)")
})
public class Pharmacy {
   //...
}
```

The repository that I've created to access database is one that seen below:

```java
@Repository
public interface PharmacyRepository extends JpaRepository<Pharmacy, Long> {
    
}
```

When I make `pharmacyFilter` enabled, everything works fine and the filter applied on all queries. You can see the query generated for `repository.findAll()` as follows:

```sql
select pharmacy0_.id as id1_0_, pharmacy0_.name as name2_0_ from pharmacy pharmacy0_ where pharmacy0_.id in (select user.pharmacy_id from user where user.id = ?)
```

But, the problem occurred when I want to try using `repository.findById(ID id)`. When I use the mentioned method, the filter won't applied to the final query and we will see the following sql in the terminal:

```sql
select pharmacy0_.id as id1_0_0_, pharmacy0_.name as name2_0_0_ from pharmacy pharmacy0_ where pharmacy0_.id=?
```

I guessed the problem is due to using id multiple times. One in `findById` and another in filter condition. But when I tried to create query using `session` object, this problem didn't occurred and output is desirable:

```sql
select pharmacy0_.id as id1_0_, pharmacy0_.name as name2_0_ from pharmacy pharmacy0_ where pharmacy0_.id in (select user.pharmacy_id from user where user.id = ?) and pharmacy0_.id=2
```

The problem is resolved using the following approach, but what happens when we use the JpaRepository#findById default implementation?

```java
@Query(value = "from Pharmacy where id = :id")
Optional<Pharmacy> findById(Long id);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't even work for findAll() for me, even after enabling the filter explicitly by `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter("myFilter").setFilterParam("myParam", "myValue");` The code is accepted, the filter is enabled, I did it exactly like above. But it's just not working., the condition is not added to the query. Giving up on this. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it is stated in the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter):

> Filters apply to entity queries, but not to direct fetching.

But under the hood `repository.findById(ID id)` method calls `EntityManager.find`.
So, this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, is there any other way to force not using `EntityManager::find`? (Instead of what I've tried in the question).

Comment: I do not see another way as joust write own query, like you did.

Comment: This should be fixed in Hibernate 6 Beta 1. See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14772

Comment: Appreciate this, thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Hi there try this will apply any filter by bypass default springboot findById

```java
@Repository
public interface PharmacyRepository extends JpaRepository<Pharmacy, Long> {
    

   @Override
    default Optional<Pharmacy> findById(Long id) {
        return findOne(Example.of(Pharmacy.builder().id(id).build()));
        // or with predicate
    }
}
```